# C# Adding elements of a List to a 2 dimensional Array in a special way

Tags: c#, arrays, list, datatables, html-agility-pack

my problem is the following (C# enviroment):
I got a table in a HTML document. I extracted the tables using HTMLAgilityPack and Regular Expressions. All the cells are saved in a List of strings.
Now I want so save these tables in a two dimensional array like a common table. The problem is, that the rows are not having the same length. The tables are written in this way (the ... dots are empty space):

| aaa | 123 | 456 |

| ....... | 986 | 468 |

| bbb | 507 | 206 |

| ........ | 450 | 256 |

The "aaa" in the first column applies to the first and second row, the "bbb" to the 3. and 4. row, and so on.
Now I need some kind of logic to tell the Array to fill it from the List in the right way like:

| aaa | 123 | 456 |

| aaa | 986 | 468 |

| bbb | 507 | 206 |

| bbb | 450 | 256 |

None of these ideas are fix, we don't have to use a List or an Array, these are just my first ideas. If you have an idea for a logic to fill the Array or a complete different, but better way, I would be very thankfull!

IMPORTANT EDIT: the missing cell could be in any column of the table, not just in the first position!!! Like:

| aaa | 123 | 456 |

| aaa | ....... | 468 |

| bbb | 507 | 206 |

| bbb | 450 | ....... |

Now the dots in the second row are belonging to the "123" and the dots in the last row are belonging to the " 206".

```
        string[,] DataArray = new string[4, 3]; // just an example size for the table above
     List<string> Data = new List<string>(); // the cells from the HTML table are saved here

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(myHtmlDoc);

        foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td"))
                {
                    Data.Add(cell.InnerText);
                }
            }
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < DataArray.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < DataArray.GetLength(1); j++)
            {                                  
                // some logic in here to pick the right part of the List and put it in the 
                // right position in the Array
            }
        }
```

Comment: `List<string> Data` is a flat list of string... so it does not indicate, when you iterate thru it, which column the current item belongs to.. If you know the structure of the HTML table, e.g. first column is Id, 2nd column is Name, etc, then you should try to store the data from HTML table to an array of class objects.

Comment: This looks like an interesting problem. So is it correct to think that the letter values (like aaa and bbb) are like a key, and the numeric values (like 123 and 456) are values belonging to this key?

Are the keys distinct and unique? 

Why on the fourth row on your table is the 'key' set to aaa? Should this not be bbb?

Comment: @Rask sorry, the aaa in the last line was an error, it should be bbb. I fixed this. It's right that the letters are like a key for the following data.  And yes, the keys are distinct and unique for each table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that will work for you using Linq and returning a Dictionary. My apologies, as I appreciate it may not make a whole lot of sense if you are new to C#. I can maybe come back later and add some more explanation.

I've made the assumption that the values can be parsed to int. The values that cannot be parsed to int is simply discarded in this solution.

```
string runningKey = "";

Dictionary<string, List<int>> dictionary =
    doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table")
        .SelectMany(t => t.SelectNodes("tr"))
        .Select(tr => tr.SelectNodes("td|th").ToList())
        .Where(tds => tds.Any())
        .Select(
            (tds) =>
            {
                runningKey = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tds.First().InnerText) ? runningKey : tds.First().InnerText;

                return
                    new
                    {
                        Key = runningKey,
                        Values =
                            tds
                                .Skip(1)
                                .Select(td => int.TryParse(td.InnerText, out int result) ? result : -1)
                                .Where(n => n != -1)
                                .ToList()
                    };
            })
        .GroupBy(v => v.Key)
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.SelectMany(v => v.Values).ToList());
```

Hope this helps!